# Invalid Qualifier when using System.IO.path in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm extremely new to vba and feel like I have been falling down at the first hurdle all morning. I'm trying to get the path of my access file by doing the following

```
Sub getDirectoryPath()
    Debug.Print (System.IO.path.GetFullPath())
End Sub
```

However I get an "Invalid Qualifier" error on System when I try to run it. I've tried adding the 'System' reference but then it says IO is not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Path of the same Access file from which the VBA is executed?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Why not using `CurrentProject.FullName` ?

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. I hadn't used it because I'm way too new to access and vba to know about it and System.IO.path.GetFullPath() was the only answer popping up on google. Any idea why System was failing?

Comment: Are you using VBA or VB.NET cause Sytem.IO looks like .NET code.

Comment: VBA. That must be it. I wasn't too sure of the differences when I started working on it  but I think I must have been using .NET in a VBA project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA environment has only access to COM (and COM visible) component.
So forget about importing usual .Net namespaces.
**But** some Wrappers exists : [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.heyscriptingguy.aspx]
For instance this works :

```
DataList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

BTW, in order to parse file full name in VBA, you can use **FileSystemObject**.